# How to collect logs from cloud based services?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I want to collect logs from cloud based service for example AWS(Amazon Web service) using java. Can Anyone help me for how to start and collect there logs?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon provides CloudWatch, a cloud-based log service.  It collects logs and allows you to create notifications and alarms.  Most AWS services are already integrated with CloudWatch, but it really depends what kind of cloud service you're using.

If you're simply running an EC2 instance, Amazon provides [CloudWatch Logs Agent](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/QuickStartEC2Instance.html) which can push any log files (system or application) to CloudWatch.

From Java, you can also use the [AWSLogs API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/logs/AWSLogs.html), which allows you to programatically log data to CloudWatch